# Сделать несколько плиток

Tags: java, android

С помощью чего мне реализовать следующее?

Нужно чтоб на экране выводились 4 кликакбельные плитки, в которых размещено изображение и текст, типа как тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только мне нужно всего 4 таких.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно фиксированное количество таких плиток, и их немного, то использование виджетов списков, как `RecyclerView` с адаптерами излишне сложное решение.

Используйте один из табличных контейнеров, как `GridLayout`,`TableLayout` и разместите в их ячейках виджеты `CardView`, которые будут содержать нужную разметку.

Если информация плиток статична (всегда одно и то же), то указывайте их прямо в xml-разметке, иначе получаете доступ из кода к элементам контейнера и сэтите туда свою информацию.

Answer (score 3):

1. `RecyclerView`+ `GridLayoutManager`

или

2. `GridLayout`

Готовить вместе с кастомной разметкой любого вида приправленной поисковой выдачей гугла на упомянутые в ответе классы (далее `КЛАСС`).

Запрашивать у гугла надо следующее:

> `КЛАСС` android example