# Создание большой матрицы из View компонентов

Tags: android, kotlin, view

При создании большой матрицы появились некоторые проблемы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
1) Во-первых, производительность. Android Studio не рекомендует размещать свыше 80 элементов на одном экране (bad for performance). К слову, действительно анимации становятся дерганными.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Во-вторых, обработка нажатий. Существуют ли какие-то варианты, кроме ветвления по `case`?

3) Последний вопрос немного про другое. Эти элементы находятся во фрагменте. По нажатии нужно менять их значение. Отсюда вопрос: как именно необходимо реализовать обработку, чтобы был доступ ко всем компонентам TextView?

Comment: Что это за матрица и для каких целей?

Comment: Двоичный таймер. Сперва нужно задать время, а после идет отсчет. Для первого достаточно выбрать нужные биты, нажав на них. Во время отсчета значение изменяется, показывая оставшееся время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Подумайте о реализации своего функционала внутри одной View. Создаете свой класс, наследованный от View, и в onDraw рисуете нужные вам циферки в нужных вам местах, высчитанных из размеров объекта. Все данные для отображения храните внутри вью, и если надо заменить значение ячейки вызываете ее метод set(x,y,value), вместо  textViewXY.setText(value). Это значительно упростит жизнь приложению, рассчитывать внутри одного метода положение 80 элементов куда проще, чем прогон деревьев вызовов onMeasure и onLayout для этих же элементов.

2) Не совсем понятно что имеете ввиду под ветвлением. Вы можете в цикле пройтись по всем textView и повесить на каждый свой листенер, чтоб он сразу работал с нужными параметрами. Примерно так:

```
TextView[][] textViewTable; //таблица ваших textView

for (int i = 0; i < textViewTable.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < textViewTable[i].length; j++){
         final int I = i;
         final int J = j;
         textViewTable[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener(){
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
                   onItemClick(I,J)
              }
         })
}
```

Не самый оптимальный вариант, но от кейса избавит. Еще можно положить каждому TextView в tag идентификатор, например вида "x:y", парсить его при клике и вызывать соответствующее событие.

Ну и если вы реализуете свою вью, как я предлагал в пункте 1), вопрос отпадает, так как вам придется выяснять куда пользователь попал по координатам клика.

3) Если вы еще не положили все свои TextView в массив - сделайте это. Кроме того, я бы рекомендовал создавать их в цикле в коде, а не в xml, и не плодить кучи бессмысленных id и findViewById. Если у вас вопрос как связать кнопку с активити с текстВью, то создайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: Можете подробнее описать реализацию метода `set`? Не совсем понятно, как именно заменять уже нарисованный элемент.

Comment: у вас в объекте хранится матрица значений. Метод set изменяет нужное значение в матрице и вызывает полную перерисовку объекта. Если говорить о произволительности, нарисовать 1000 текстов в onDraw вьюшки будет заметно быстрее, чем 80 отдельных View  в лайаутах. Лично убедился)

Comment: Сейчас печатаю текст методом `canvas.drawText()`. Как после этого изменить уже напечатанное значение? У `canvas` существует какой-то специальный метод? Если выводить другой текст с теми же координатами, то они попросту накладываются друг на друга.

Comment: после смены значения вызовите для вьюшке invalidate, и она полностью перерисуется с нуля

Comment: С обработкой нажатий разобрался, однако появился другой вопрос. Необходимо, чтобы элемент подстраивался по размеру ко всем актуальным разрешениям. То есть нужно получить одинаковое отображение на всех устройствах, - как на скриншоте. Сейчас есть мысли насчет сложных формул и некоторых констант для определенных разрешений, но можно ли проще?

Comment: В момент изменения размеров вам нужно рассчитать размер текста и положения каждого элемента. Очень поможет в этом деле вунция у объекта Paint -  getTextBounds. Она позволяет для конкретного текста для конкретной Paint выяснять сколько пикселей по высоте и ширине займет указанный текст. Этот процесс запускать в переопределенной функции View.layout или добавить слушатель через addOnLayoutChangeListener

Comment: Скажем, возможно ли программно сделать что-то наподобие `layout_weight`? Чтобы у каждого отступа (`space`) был свой "вес"?

Comment: Конечно. Очень простая формула. У вас Х надписей в строке. Значит количество отступов = Х+1. делим ширину вьюшки на x+1, получаем размер одного отступа. теперь x - центр первой надписи. 2x - центр второй и т.д. В Paint вы можете указать align для текста. Поставьте center, и тогда можно рисовать текст с положением по высоте = width * i/(x+1)

Comment: Заметил некую странность: от первой цифры до левой грани дисплея определенное расстояние, а от последней до правой уже другое, хотя, судя по вычислениям, рассчитано все верно. Существует какой-нибудь способ точной проверки?

Comment: Похоже, это действительно так. Как думаете, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94212/discussion-between---and-marionette).

Answer (score 0):

Начните например из RecyclerView c четырьмя элементами в строку [(плитка например)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453762/238266). И соответственно вы получите id - элемента, добавляете слушатель на item который будет возвращать этот самый id